# В созданном шаблоне отсутствует файл с исходным кодом

Tags: c++, windows

При создании шаблона проекта С++ в Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, проект собирается,  шаблон создается, устанавливается, но в нем отсутствует файл с исходным кодом. 
Попытка добавить файл вручную в zip шаблона не срабатывает. Если распаковать шаблон, добавить файл исходника и запустить проект, все прекрасно работает. Буду признателен если кто подскажет, как это исправить.

Comment: вряд ли вас интересует ответ на вопрос, *сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с подобным явлением*. переформулируйте, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав [edit].

Comment: Похоже , проблема связана с Update 3. Visual Studio Update1 создает шаблоны без ошибок.